# Shared Log File reading between processes

Tags: c, windows, winapi, theory

Looking for some advice on handling this:

ProgA (unmanaged code) writes to a log file.
I can alter the log location (maybe even direct to a pipe).

ProgB (managed code - C - windows) needs to read the log file after specific events.

What Im trying to accomplish is to have ProgB reading the ProgA log file after such events (which are triggered by ProgB).
The synchronization of this would be easy if the log was directly written by ProgA ... but its not. It seems to buffer itself internally to ProgA or maybe its the filesystem write that is buffered or both. Either way the write is delayed and they delay varies by a lot.

Looking for suggestions of a technique to use here to make the reading as speedy and seemless as possible?

A couple rough ideas I had are,

WaitForSingleObject - not sure if there is a standard object here that would be useful.

Some other filesystem or file level events I can hook into?

Timed loop to just poll file size changes - ugly but Im sure it would work, would conveniently give me the amount of new data to read.

Pipe the log file in someway for ProgB access?

Figure out the buffer size and always make sure after my interactions that the size is hit (forcing an immediate write) - extra ugly, worst case.

Hijack ProgA WriteFile() via dll injection. (would rather not alter ProgA in any way though)

Something else entirely?

Comment: Can you modify the unmanaged code?  Add `fflush` so it writes the buffered output promptly.

Comment: If you can modify the log emitter, you could also make it write the logs to a queue (RabbitMQ, MongoDB to name just two) or pulse a named event that the receiver waits for. If you can't change it, you'll have to resort to hacks, like hooking calls or DLL injection or similar stuff.